# How to read value key pair form xml using boost ptree

Tags: c++, xml, boost, boost-propertytree

I have the following structure of an xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section name="pvf">
    <section name="p1">
        <item value="92.31335795746914" key="x"/>
        <item value="-746.7962776760924" key="y"/>
        <item value="400.1902893301479" key="z"/>
        <item value="1" key="u1"/>
        <item value="7" key="type"/>
        <item value="Inlet 2" key="value"/>
    </section>
</section>
```

I like to read the `x`, `y` and `z` values into an `std::array<float,3> point`

I could itaterate over all items with

```
for (const auto &v : subtree.get_child(""))
```

and than

```
if (item.get<std::string>("<xmlattr>.key") == "x") {
    point[0] = item.get<float>"<xmlattr>.value");
}
```

and likewise for `y` and `z`.

Is there a more elegant way to read this?

Can I use the notation

```
m_level = pt.get("p1.x", 0);
```

like in the [boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/tutorial.html)

Comment: You can `item.get<float>("<xmlattr>.value")` rather than calling `stod`

Comment: True point. Is there a way to directly access the value with `key="x"`?

Comment: It doesn't look like it. The path syntax is very simplistic